# jQuery Validate input on blur and ajax posting

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I have a form that is handled by ajax and uses jQuery validate for validation. It's working as intended but when I add field validation on blur of form fields, it stops working correctly. It stops posting via ajax and instead just goes to the php file used to process ajax. It also doesn't seem to handle the file upload properly, says there isn't one when there is. Going back via the browser after a failed post and resubmitting then works okay though. So I'm not sure what's going on.

Here's the JS:

```
    // highlight input fields on blur - This is what stops it working
    $('.input-field').on('focusout', function(){
        $(this).parents('form').validate({
            onfocusout: function(element) {
                this.element(element);
            },
            onkeyup: false
        });
    });

    // Ajax form submit/validation
    $(document).on('click', '.form-submit', function(e){

        // Whichever form sent it..
        var $thisForm = $(this).parents('form');

        // Validate it...
        $thisForm.validate({
            ignore: '',
            rules: {
                upload: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {

                var formData = new FormData($thisForm[0]);

                // Show the loading spinner
                $thisForm.addClass('loading').find('.padded').remove();

                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    url: $thisForm.attr('action'),
                    success: function(data) {
                        // When we're done, remove spinner and add the thank you message
                        $thisForm.parents('aside').addClass('textcenter padded').html(data.message);
                        $('.loading').removeClass('loading');
                    }
                 });
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code...

```
// highlight input fields on blur - This is what stops it working
$('.input-field').on('focusout', function(){
    $(this).parents('form').validate({....
```

And this...

```
// Ajax form submit/validation
$(document).on('click', '.form-submit', function(e){
    ....
    // Validate it...
    $thisForm.validate({ ....
```

`.validate()` cannot be attached to an individual field along with its initialization options as you've done.

You totally misunderstand the purpose of the `.validate()` method.  `.validate()` is only the method for *initializing* the plugin on your form.  It is NOT the method of testing.  Testing is performed automatically, because the plugin is capturing the click of the button, and various other events,  for automatic triggering.

You would never put `.validate()` inside of a `focusout` or `click` handler.  Validation is triggered automatically upon "focus out" and "click" as per the defaults of this plugin.

You simply need to initialize it properly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  // DOM is loaded

    $('.forms').each(function() {   // select all forms
        $(this).validate({          // initialize plugin on each form
            // options              // your plugin options
        });;
    });

});
```

- `.validate()` goes inside of the DOM ready even handler function to initialize the plugin when the page loads.
- When `.validate()` is attached to more than one form at a time, like with a class selector, the method only works on the *first matched element*.  You need to use a jQuery `.each()` in order to get around this.

Refer to the following...

- [Stack Overflow tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info)
- [Documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)
- [Working code from other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-validate)

Comment: Oh wow, you're right I had it so wrong then didn't I! I think I made it more complicated than it actually was... Works like a charm now, and it'll certainly make future projects much easier! :) Thanks Sparky.